# travelling to the Schengen area on two separate Visas?

Tags: schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I will be travelling to Spain from the 7th to the 16th of Jan, 2020 on 2 multiple entry Schengen visit visas.

My old visa (a 2 year multiple entry visit visa) was valid till the 14th of Jan but since the conference I am travelling for lasts till the 16th, I applied to the Spanish embassy for a second visa, which they issued from the 15th of Jan to the 15th of July.

I'm wondering if I will face any issue at immigration since my stay is covered by two separate visas.

Comment: I would not expect that. You'll get an entry stamp, and later an exit stamp, and as long as you respect the 90/180 rule you will be OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have no problem, for the reasons given by @KristvanBesien.

A Schengen C-Visa allows you to enter and exit **within** it's validity

- the 2nd Visa extends the validity of the first

Unless the amount of days is **explicitly** stated in the visa

- the 90/180 days rule applies